# Can から mean それでは?

Tags: grammar, particle-から

A: もう用がねぇなら帰るけど

B: 用がないわけじゃないけど
   今日はなんかタイミングがよくない

A: じゃあ帰る**から**な

I would like to know if kara is used commonly in Japanese to say also "in that case" (besides of "because"), or is it used as a softener or for another reason in this context?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> から 〘接続助詞〙
>   ❻《文末に用いて》**注意・警告・慰め**などの気持ちを表す。
>   「先生に言いつけてやる**から**。」「私もう帰る**から**。」「心配しなくていい**から**。」

The conjunctive particle から at the end of a sentence can express a feeling of 注意・警告・慰め (cautioning, warning, comforting/cheering up). Here in your context the から is not "because" or "so", but expresses soft/mild 注意 or 警告, adding a nuance of "~~, alright? / okay? / you see?" etc. It is daily used in real life as in 「じゃ、(もう)帰る**から**(ね)。」「じゃ、(もう)行く**から**(ね)。」 etc. to mean "Well/Okay, I'm going home / leaving now (, alright?)"

Comment: Where can I find this book?

Comment: @LonelyDriver, The dictionary 明鏡国語辞典 is available on [Amazon Japan](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s?k=%E6%98%8E%E9%8F%A1%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8&__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&ref=nb_sb_noss), [楽天市場](https://search.rakuten.co.jp/search/mall/%E6%98%8E%E9%8F%A1%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/200162/), etc.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, as you mentioned, から is a softener, for making the parting of ways not so harsh.

### Without the から: a bit cold

> じゃあ帰る
>
> Alright, I'm going home.

### With the から: adds the sense of "if there's anything else you want to talk about, please bring it up now, because I plan to go home now."

> じゃあ帰るから（他に話すことがあるなら今話そうね。なければ、また会いましょう。）
>
> Alright, I'm going home, so...(if there's anything else you want to talk about, please bring it up now, because I plan to go home now.)

### EDIT (additional comment): Generally, the meaning of the "elliptical" から can vary depending on situation.

A different example from the one above:

> もう、帰るから！
>
> I'm leaving! (...so don't talk to me, because I'm angry, frustrated,
> etc.)

Comment: Wouldn't またね be more suitable here, instead of また会いましょう? The rest of the conversation is pretty casual.

Comment: The whole elliptical bit is implied so it doesn't *really* matter which they used, but また会おう·会いましょう is probably better for conveying the sense that the speaker is opening to speaking with the listener again.

Comment: Thank you so much, Otomatonium! Now I understand that から!