# ガードがばがばになっから meaning

Tags: slang, manga, definitions

I'm having trouble making sense of this sentence. From what I've looked up, I think it's probably either "meme" talk, a dialect joke, or some combination of the two. Here's the full sentence:

バカがガードがばがばになっからなマジで。

This is from a manga. Two highschool girls are talking, and one of them bought a love potion from the internet. Her friend is doubtful of its effectiveness, but she says "no, no, it seriously works", mentioning that she'd even tested it on girls. She describes its effectiveness as バカ効き a few times throughout the manga so far because it ends up having unexpectedly erotic results.

If I'm breaking the sentence apart correctly, she's describing マジで; in other words, she's talking about how マジ the effectiveness of the love potion is. If that's correct, the description is バカがガードがばがばになっから.

がばがば could mean "oversized", "gag", or "baggy (like clothing)" according to Google. I assume ガード is just "guard", like the kind a person might let down if under the effects of a love potion, though that doesn't seem to make sense here. For なっから I found a meaning on fukapedia that says it's 深谷地方の方言 and is equivalent to とても or たいへん... but that again doesn't seem to fit properly.

I'd really appreciate any help with the word definitions themselves, or a hint as to how I might be breaking it down improperly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **バカが**: "You fool!"

  - **が**: not a subject marker but a vocative-like particle; see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72075/5010)
- **ガード**: [noun] "guard" (in this context, refers to psychological defense or skepticism against the seducer)
- **がばがば**: [onomatopoeic na-adj] describes how something is wide open, very loose or leaky
- **に**: destination/target marker ("to")
- **なっから**: colloquialism for なるから (forget the little-known dialect; なっから is slangy but common in standard Japanese)

  - **なる**: "to become"
  - **から**: "you know"; "listen"; "mind you"; "I warned you" (see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58119/5010))
- **な**: sentence-end particle
- **マジで**: "seriously"; "really"

Note that the subject of the sentence is ガード rather than バカ. The very literal translation is "You're silly, the (recipient's) defense will be extremely loose, you know, seriously." The sentence effectively means anyone who takes this potion will forget how to defend themselves.

**EDIT:** We also say すっか/すっから (するか/するから), やっか/やっから (やるか/やるから), みっか/みっから (みるか/みるから), and less commonly くっか/くっから (くるか/くるから).

Comment: Alternatively “バカ” could be the subject and “ガードがばがば” the complement. Usually the “vocative” 〜が comes after a remark I think.

Comment: @JerryFielder In that case, the sentence would mean "Fools will have a loose guard", but I doubt that matches the context.

Comment: Well she describes it as “バカ利き”, meaning it works on idiots. So to me this sounds like, “Cuz idiots let up their guard. Seriously.”

Comment: @JerryFielder Nope, バカ利き means "insanely effective" or "works like crazy", but not "works on idiots". It's just an slangy emphatic way of "very effective".

Comment: ah I see, thanks for pointing that out