# What does the word 「くれてやっかい」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

I am not sure if it would be a combination of the word 「くれてやる」and the word 厄{やっ}介{かい} which means trouble or support.

Here is the sentence I found the word. It was said by a boxer during a fight. He was more advantage than his opponent at that time.

> こりずにきたな...いっちょうカウンターでも**くれてやっかい**

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/76420/5010 (see the last part of my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

くれてやっかい is a contraction of くれてやるかい. The word 厄介 is not related.

In general, るか **may** contact to っか in very informal speech:

- するか → すっか
- やるか → やっか
- 見るか → 見っか
- なるか → なっか
- 来るか → くっか
- 生きるか → 生きっか, 食べるか → 食べっか, ...

すっか/やっか are relatively common, but others are uncommon. I probably have not heard 乗っか, 寄っか, 切っか, 取っか, 怒っか and so on, so this works with only a few common verbs that end with る.