# Meaning of したくすっか

Tags: translation

I am reading 海街 Diary, and I have come across the below dialogue.
For context: A female character receives some text messages. She tells her boyfriend that it's work-related and she has to go. The boyfriend asks:

> さて俺もしたくすっか。

I can guess that the meaning is "Well then, do you want me to (go) as well?", but what does すっか mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

すっか is a contraction of するか (cf. [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82681/45489)). So the phrase is さて俺もしたくするか meaning "Now I will do my preparation (for going out), too".

- したく is [支度](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%94%AF%E5%BA%A6/#je-31600), which means preparation for something. (E.g. 旅行の支度 means packing).
- Here も means 'also'. So literally, *Also I....*