Can't understand a sentence (お前調子のってんじゃねーぞ、ボコっぞこの野郎）
In this video, (https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx4M52I5wZZrId9bzx-tvJB2SaXkjWGcLx?si=PTgiXkezH__D4igS), I can't understand this sentence.

お前調子のってんじゃねーぞ、ボコっぞこの野郎


I think there are some grammar that I don't know yet here(like ~ぞ expression).
Could anyone break this sentence down and explain to me how this translates to
Stop being a smartass or I'm gonna beat you up

? I have looked up the words but can't figure out why those words translate to the above sentence..

Let me break it down:
お前 (vocative) "You"
調子のってんじゃねー -- 調子に乗って(い)るんじゃない
ぞ -- (masculine) final particle
ボコっぞ -- ボコるぞ "(I) will beat (you) up"
この野郎 (derogatory) "You bastard"

に in 調子に乗って is omitted. 「調子に乗る」  means "get carried away". Related thread:

Questions on the phrase 調子に乗る

～てんじゃねえ is a slurred pronunciation of ～ているんじゃない.
ているの gets contracted to てるん ⇒ てん. Related threads:

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30057/9831
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/9831
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53669/9831

では ⇒ じゃ.
ない ⇒ ねえ. Related thread:

Changing of vowels at the end of words to え

ボコるぞ gets contracted to ボコっぞ. Related thread:

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82681/9831

ボコる (≈ ボコボコにする) means "beat up".

Wow, that contained many grammars I didn't know. Thank you.

Japanese
お前調子のってんじゃねーぞ、ボコっぞこの野郎
↓
調子のってんじゃねーぞ/ お前/ (それ続けるなら)/ ボコるぞ/この野郎
↓
お前/ 調子に乗るな/ (それを続けるなら)/ ボコボコにするぞ/この野郎

↓↓↓　↓↓↓　↓↓↓　↓↓↓　↓↓↓

English
you/ stop acting like a dickhead./ (If you keep that up)/ I'll beat the shit out of you/ you little prick.
↓
Quit acting like a jerk. If you keep that attitude up, I'll kick your ass, you jerk
⇣
If you keep that shit up, I'll fuck you up, jerk.

Thanks that cleared it a little more.
