# What's the meaning of "からねぇ" used in the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, words, usage, word-usage

I frequently saw or heard the word "**から**" in some Japanese TV shows, I know the word basically means "since" or "from", but it seems can't always be translated like that.

Here's a sentence from the caption of a Japanese TV show:

"ここは もう 何年も 使ってない部屋らしい**からねぇ**。"

The English translation is "It seems that this room hasn't been used for years."

The meaning "since" or "from" all don't match the translation, so what exactly does "**からねぇ**" mean in this sentence?

Comment: Maybe this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58108/can-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-mean-%e3%81%9d%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af/58119#58119

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks for sharing the link, the answers in that page are exactly what I was looking for. I think that's the correct answer to my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Eddie Kal , yes, it does, I had confirmed in the comment above.

Comment: Oh that was a system auto-generated comment from my duplicate suggestion. I didn't even notice that comment was posted. Once you confirm the duplicate, the comment will automatically disappear. Voila.

Comment: @Eddie Kal , oh I see. Now I've confirmed the duplicate.

Comment: @PhilipChou, Can you give the surrounding context? Since it doesn't appear to me that the から has the same meaning as the から in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Chocolate Sorry for the late response, I had not come to this site for a long time so I just saw your comment. The surrounding context is like this: The location is in a hotel on a remote island, the island has no visitors for a long time and therefore no cleaners work there, so the hotel is dirty and needs to be cleaned by guests themselves. A guy is about to clean a hotel room, and another guy stands next to him, then a woman (one of their friends) comes in, looks around the room (the room is dirty as mentioned above), and said to the two guys: "ここは もう 何年も 使ってない部屋らしいからねぇ。"